# Unable to view postscript files using psv in TeX Live on Windows

Tags: texlive, windows, ghostscript, postscript

I installed TeX Live 2019 on Windows 10 last year and tried to use the built-in psv to read postscript files. It opened with an error message, which I cannot remember now. This year, I installed TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10 and again tried to use psv. This time, it does not even open.

I know that postscript files can be easily converted to PDF files using the built-in tools of TeX Live, but I do want to know what went wrong. Just to be able to read the postscript files without converting them to PDF, I then installed ghostscript from ghostscript.com and gsview from ghostgum.com.au. With these, the postscript files could be viewed.

I remember that there were no problems with psv in earlier releases of TeX Live. What went wrong with psv, and is there a fix?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  With information, which you provide, is not possible to help you. At least you need to add copy of errors, which you get.

Comment: ps_view is not maintained. It does not work under
newer Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0):

As Akira mentioned, psv is currently non-functional, and nobody has stepped forward yet to fix it.

As a workaround, there is now a simple utility psviewer which converts eps- and ps files to temporary pdf files and shows them in the default pdf viewer. It can be invoked from the command-line or by right-clicking the eps or pdf in a file manager.

psviewer should become part of any fully-updated windows texlive installation, as part of the wintools.win32 package.